# Fiber of normalisation morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral, excellent scheme and $\eta: \widetilde{X} \to X$ be its normalization. If $x \in X$ is a closed point there is the following powerful tool (from EGA, Ch IV, 7.8.3, vii) to find the fibre of $\eta$ over $x$ (ie. $\widetilde{X} \times_X \mathrm{Spec}(k(x))$):
$$\widetilde{X} \times_X \mathrm{Spec} (\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}) \cong \text{Normalization of }\mathrm{Spec} (\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}).$$ 
Here $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$ is the completed local ring at $x$.

If we replace the completed local ring by the completion of the strict Henselization $\widehat{\mathcal{O}^{\mathrm{sh}}}_{X,x}$ the isomorphism is again true due to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CBM.

However, 
$\eta^{-1}(x)$ is in bijection with $\widetilde{X} \times_X \mathrm{Spec} (\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x})$. Is that true for $\widehat{\mathcal{O}^{\mathrm{sh}}}_{X,x}$.

I am interested in the case where $X$ is a fibered surface over a Dedekind scheme $S$ in the sense of [Liu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199202494).

Comment: Sorry, yes this is only true for excellent schemes. I have changed the question now.